# Appearance of strange characters in the written file

Tags: python, numpy

I am unable to write the output values as they are to a file . Kindly help.

```
import numpy as np
theta=10
sigma=np.linspace(0,10,300)
Re=np.linspace(5,100,300)


file = open("New values sigma7.txt", "w")

for i in np.arange(0,300):
    mu=np.sqrt(Re[i]*sigma)
    A=(mu-1)*np.exp(mu)+(mu+1)*np.exp(-mu)
    B=2*mu*(theta-1)
    C=(A/B)

    D1=np.exp(mu)/2*(mu+sigma)
    D2=np.exp(-mu)/2*(mu-sigma)
    D3=mu**2
    D4=np.exp(-sigma)
    D5=sigma
    D6=mu**2-sigma**2
    D7=D3*D4
    D8=D5*D6
    H=D7/D8
    D9=(1/sigma)
    D=D1-D2+H-D9
    K1=C-D
    K2=np.delete(K1,0)
    K3=np.nonzero(K2>0)
    K33=np.array(K3)
    K4=np.shape(K3)
    K5=len(K33.T)
    K6=K5+1
    K7=sigma[K6]
    K77=np.array(K7)
    print K77
    np.save(file, K77)

file.close()
```

The output is given by K77 which is a set of 300 numeric values. However, when I write the file, I get the following several times when I open it.

```
“NUMPY F {'descr': '<f8', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (), }
```

Please help in this regard.

Comment: Please show us *how* you're opening the file and reading its contents.

Comment: I am simply saving it to the directory where I have saved the python file and opening from there. That is, going to the specific folder and then clicking that saved file.

Comment: So you're trying to open a binary numpy file as a text document.  This won't work.  You should open it using the numpy library within python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want text, use

file.write('%g\n" % K77)

np.save saves in numpy's binary format.

Comment: @user3738922 I would recommend you also explicitly open your file in utf-8 format with `file = open("filename.txt", encoding="utf-8")`, that way you guarantee that `file.write` writes in an encoding that you can read. Check out the [Dive Into Python book](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/files.html) for some great file I/O tutorials and other useful stuff.

Comment: @user3738922 Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem. You can accept an answer by clicking on the tick mark on the left side of the answer! This is the way to says thanks in SO.